# Spacing of dynamic items in flex container

Tags: html, css

I am wondering what is the best method for spacing dynamic items in a flex container. The items in the container can removed or added. I set the container to display flex and justify-content flex start so they appear from left to right which is how I want them to be displayed. Each item in the contain has margin-right for spacing. Is this the best way to do it or is there a better way?

here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/39vsmyxo/49/

```
<div class = "container">
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Look into [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content#examples).

Comment: What is the **desired** output? I assume that you want them all to be on a single line? It's impossible to know what the 'best' approach is when it is unknown what you're trying to achieve. And even then the 'best' approach is likely subjective.

Comment: I'd suggest using the `gap` property in the container and if you're unsure about the number of items maybe `flex-wrap`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gap: 16px;`. It will work on grids too. Also we have `justify-content: space-evenly;` and `justify-content: space-between;`. You can try them.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, it seems you want some gap between flex-items, then you can use `gap` property but it may not support in all browsers. So you can do select `div` whose adjacent element is a `div` like

```
.container > div + div{
    margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

**This will work if there is no flex-wrap**

But there may be a chance that you change markup in the future so your style sheet should work in that case also so you can use universal selector `*` here to select any type of direct child.

```
.container > * + *{
    margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.container > * + * {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
</div>
```